# particular solution of the equation $D²y+Dy+y=x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm searching a particular solution of the equation $D²y+Dy+y=x$. 
Where D  is the differentiation operator. I already tried to do something looking like $(D+1) (D+1)y=x$ but it doesn't work  as it gives me $D²y+2Dy+y=x$... Do you have any idea?
In fact I may see how to do for an order of 1 but not when the order is 2.

Comment: Just a thought: What happens when you differentiate again and subtract the equations?

Comment: Not the simplest method in this case, but you could use series expansion to get at:
$$y = \frac1{1+D+D^2}x \implies (1-D+D^3-D^4+...)x = (1-D)x = x-1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the polynomial $p(X) = X^2 + X + 1$ does not have real roots, there is no factorization over $\mathbf R$ in two linear factors, hence $p(D) = D^2 + D + 1$ cannot be written as product of two order 1 operators.

But: As the right hand side $x$ is an degree 1 polynomial, let's start with the ansatz: $y(x) = bx + c$, giving 
$$ p(D)y = b + bx + c = x $$
or (by matching coefficients):
$$ b = 1 , \;  b+ c = 0 $$
therefore $y(x) = x-1$ is a particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $y$ is a polynomial in $x$, then $D^2 y + D y + y$ is a polynomial with the same leading term.